# Retrieve multiple values from JSON

Tags: python, json

I have the function defined which retrieves the required value from my JSON string

2 Part question:

```
def galPrice(commodity):
    comPrice = [item['meanPrice'] for item in data['lastStarport']['commodities']
        if item['name'] == commodity]
print json.dumps(comPrice)
```

## Question 1:

The value returned from the above function give me `[378]` how would I return the item name as well as the value i.e. `[meanPrice : 378]`

## Question 2:

From this example I am trying to print multiple selected values such as `meanPrice`, `buyPrice` and `sellPrice`

so the output would give me:

```
[meanPrice : 378],
[buyPrice : 224],
[sellPrice : 209]
```

The only way I can figure it out is by doing the following I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this.

```
def galPrice(commodity):
    meanPrice = [item['meanPrice'] for item in data['lastStarport']['commodities']
        if item['name'] == commodity]
    buyPrice = [item['buyPrice'] for item in data['lastStarport']['commodities']
        if item['name'] == commodity]
    sellPrice = [item['sellPrice'] for item in data['lastStarport']['commodities']
        if item['name'] == commodity]
    print 'Mean Price:', meanPrice
    print 'Buy Price:', buyPrice
    print 'Sell Price:', sellPrice
```

---

JSON:

```
{"lastStarport":{"id":"3230614016","name":"Vries Installation","faction":"Independent","commodities":[{"id":"128049204","name":"Explosives","cost_min":300,"cost_max":456,"cost_mean":"378.00","homebuy":"60","homesell":"56","consumebuy":"4","baseCreationQty":368,"baseConsumptionQty":0,"capacity":3868,"buyPrice":224,"sellPrice":209,"meanPrice":378,"demandBracket":0,"stockBracket":2,"creationQty":3868,"consumptionQty":0,"targetStock":3868,"stock":2166,"demand":0,"rare_min_stock":"0","rare_max_stock":"0","market_id":null,"parent_id":null,"statusFlags":[],"categoryname":"Chemicals","volumescale":"1.1400"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may as well use a helper function

```
def get_commodity_data(commodity):
    for item in data['lastStarport']['commodities']:
        if item['name'] == commodity:
            return item
    return None

def galPrice(commodity):
    comdata = get_commodity_data(commodity)
    return {
        'meanPrice': comdata['meanPrice'],
        'buyPrice': comdata['buyPrice'],
        'sellPrice': comdata['sellPrice'],
    }

print galPrice('Explosives')
```

Outputs

```
{'sellPrice': 209, 'meanPrice': 378, 'buyPrice': 224}
```

I think this code should answer 1) and 2). If not, comment below and I shall clarify.

---

If you would rather not hard code the required values, the below is a lot more flexible

```
def galPrice(commodity, values):
    comdata = get_commodity_data(commodity)
    return dict(zip(values, [comdata[value] for value in values]))

print galPrice('Explosives', ['meanPrice', 'buyPrice', 'sellPrice'])
```

It gives the same output as above.

---

Given multiple commodities with the same name, the following will give a list of data for each commodity

```
def galPrice(commodity, values):
    comdata = filter(lambda i: i['name'] == commodity,
                     data['lastStarport']['commodities'])
    return [dict(zip(values, [com[value] for value in values]))
            for com in comdata]
```

Note: this no longer requires the helper function. It utilities the inbuilt [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function, and a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

First the list is filtered down to only those items that have the required name. Then the required values are pulled from said items.

Example output:

```
[{'sellPrice': 209, 'meanPrice': 378, 'buyPrice': 224}, 
    {'sellPrice': 210, 'meanPrice': 378, 'buyPrice': 224}]
```

---

Or, if you're very comfortable with list comprehension syntax:

```
def galPrice(commodity, values):
    return [dict(zip(values, [com[value] for value in values if com['name'] == commodity]))
            for com in data['lastStarport']['commodities']]
```

With the same output as above.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking to achieve, so it would appear that the item name of `meanPrice` would be entered manually. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Marct see my update for a more flexible solution if you would rather not hard code the required values to output

Comment: Thank you this will also come in very handy

Comment: using your example on another piece of my JSON where I have multiple values of the same name but different sub values it only returns the first entry, is this correct, not sure if I am reading it wrong but I though the `for item` statement would return all values ?

Comment: @Marct I've updated with two ways of doing what you want (at the end). The second way is extremely similar to your original code - I realize I misunderstood it's original function, apologies.